# How to apply If Else statements in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a Pandas Dataframe and I am trying to add a new column where the value in the new column is dependant on some conditions in the existing Dataframe. The Dataframe I have is as follows:

| Date / Time | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-02 16:30:00 | 1.25566 | 1.25696 | 1.25439 | 1.25634 | 2720 |
| 2020-06-02 17:00:00 | 1.25638 | 1.25683 | 1.25532 | 1.25614 | 2800 |
| 2020-06-02 17:30:00 | 1.25615 | 1.25699 | 1.25520 | 1.25565 | 2827 |
| 2020-06-02 18:00:00 | 1.25565 | 1.25598 | 1.25334 | 1.25341 | 2993 |
| 2020-06-02 18:30:00 | 1.25341 | 1.25385 | 1.25272 | 1.25287 | 1899 |
| 2020-07-03 07:00:00 | 1.24651 | 1.24673 | 1.24596 | 1.24603 | 600 |
| 2020-07-03 07:30:00 | 1.24601 | 1.24641 | 1.24568 | 1.24594 | 487 |
| 2020-07-03 08:00:00 | 1.24593 | 1.24618 | 1.24580 | 1.24612 | 455 |
| 2020-07-03 08:30:00 | 1.24612 | 1.24667 | 1.24603 | 1.24666 | 552 |
| 2020-07-03 09:00:00 | 1.24666 | 1.24785 | 1.24623 | 1.24765 | 922 |

I would like to add a new column called 'Signal', which is dependant on the following if and else statements. I have written these into a Function:

```
def BullEngulf(df):   
    if (df['Open'] <= df['Close'].shift(1)) and (df['Close'] > df['Open'].shift(1)) and (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['Open'].shift(1)):
    return 'Open'
    else:
    return '0'
```

I have then tried to apply the function as follows:

```
df['Signal'] = df.apply(BullEngulf)
df
```

When I run the code, the following error message occurs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-f87af322a959> in <module>
      5         return '0'
      6 
----> 7 df['Signal'] = df.apply(BullEngulf)
      8 df

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879 
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    293 
    294             try:
--> 295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
    296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

<ipython-input-62-f87af322a959> in BullEngulf(df)
      1 def BullEngulf(df):
----> 2     if (df['Open'] <= df['Close'].shift(1)) and (df['Close'] > df['Open'].shift(1)) and (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['Open'].shift(1)):
      3         return 'Open'
      4     else:
      5         return '0'

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Open'
```

Please could somebody explain what is wrong with the code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Signal'] = np.where((df['Open'] <= df['Close'].shift(1)) &
                        (df['Close'] > df['Open'].shift(1))  &
                        (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['Open'].shift(1)),
                        'Open', '0')
```